# Printing text on terminal from a service

Tags: python, service, output, upstart

I have written a Python script and running as a service , The script itself checks for the network traffic and in the end it spits out a print statement.
I am not sure how would I see the printed text in the end .Will it display on the terminal ?

The idea is that if this script is running as a service and I am logged on , I want to see the printed result .

service.conf (Fix the run levels if there is something wrong with it as well , I can run this as the very last service)

```
description "Network Check"
author  "I am the user"

start on runlevel [234]
stop on runlevel [0156]

chdir /home/foo
exec /home/foo/test.py
respawn
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psutil
import time
final_bytes=0
diff=0
while ((final_bytes/1000000)  < 500):
    bytes = psutil.net_io_counters()
    if (bytes.bytes_recv  - diff) > 1000000:
        time.sleep(1)
        if final_bytes != 0:
                final_bytes = final_bytes + (bytes.bytes_recv  - diff)
        else:
                final_bytes =1
    else:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    diff = bytes.bytes_recv

print "Total Bytes transferred: ", final_bytes / 1000000 ,"MB"
```

Comment: Have you considered outputting the content to a syslog server or something equivelent.  This allows you to log locally or to a remote logging server as needed.  the Python logging utility has the ability to send the content to a UDP Port (514 for syslog)

Comment: @BrianCain I am very new to Ubuntu/Linux and Python , I wrote this for learning purpose and my setup is a stand alone server. Can you elaborate a bit more? Seems like Syslog is for network monitoring .

Comment: @BrianCain I think I am getting what you are saying here and I am looking into it , but on top of that my original idea was to get some sort of instant alert (maybe flashing text etc etc ) as a form of an alert. do you think that can be achieved on a a terminal ? I am sure that wont be possible if there is no user logged in . but what if I am logged in? I am more of a SCOM guy :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to set up a syslog server (local or remote) to log your output to.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

# Set up the logging
FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s ] %(message)s\n"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
_LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
sysLogServer = "127.0.0.1" # This could be a remote server address also
sysLogPort = 514
sysLogHandle = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(sysLogServer, sysLogPort))
sysLogHandle.setFormatter(logging.Formatter( __name__ + ":" + FORMAT))
_LOG.addHandler(sysLogHandle)
```

Than when you want to generate a log message you can use the setup logging function as follows:

```
_LOG.debug("Total Bytes Transfered...")
```

This should cause your code to generate UDP syslog packets.  The next step would be to set up a local syslog listener.  For example a basic guide can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53910/how-can-i-receive-syslog-logs-from-a-networked-system)

Note.  The above example is a bit more complex than necessary with the formatting, it is just the typical format I use to include function names in the output of my content.

Comment: I think I am getting what you are saying here and I am looking into it , but on top of that my original idea was to get some sort of instant alert (maybe flashing text etc etc ) as a form of an alert. do you think that can be achieved on a a terminal ? I am sure that wont be possible if there is no user logged in . but what if I am logged in?